# How to do a split string and store into a variable for future use?

Tags: java, sqlite, jxl

I have this android app that receives data from an excel file. Im using a libray to get the text from excel to a textView.I always have 3 columns in the excel I  am receiving. For that reason I want to divide the string I receive into 3 positions in order to save in sqlite the information that excel gives and put them in the respective rows of the sqlite database.I want to know how to do a proper string split and store the information. [This is the output of the app now that receives from the excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDNSw.png) Thanks for your help in advanced.

```
try {

                    AssetManager am=getAssets();
                    InputStream is=am.open("Book1.xls");
                    Workbook wb =Workbook.getWorkbook(is);
                    Sheet s=wb.getSheet(0);
                    int row =s.getRows();
                    int col=s.getColumns();
                    String xx="";

                    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
                    {
                        for (int c=0;c<col;c++)
                        {
                            Cell z=s.getCell(c,i);

                            xx=xx+z.getContents()+"\n";
                            //here I want to divide this string in three positions


                        }
                        xx=xx+"\n";




                    }
                    textView.setText(xx);
                }

                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
```

Comment: Have a look at [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) and give it a try yourself. If you don't succeed after trying it yourself, come back with a specific question.

Comment: This is a question. I know how to do a split(" ") in a string. My doubt is in storing in variables of type string and used them

Comment: I'm actually don't really understand your problem, but I think what you need is a `String`-Array, where you want to "store" the data. Check some tutorials about Arrays in java

Comment: In this case I have a variable o type string xx and I want to divide them into three strings

Comment: Have a look at the return type of `String#split`.

Comment: I have a string that came from excel, My objective is to divide this string into three different strings. Can someone show an example on how shoukd you do a split using the example I gave please?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

```
    String[] result = myString.split(" ");
    String a = result[0];
    String b = result[1];
    String c = result[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Somthing like this :

Example :

```
String test ="aaa;bbb;ccc";

String fisrt ;
String second ;
String thrid ;

if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(test)){ // test if str not null
String[] result = test .spit(";");  // you indicate your separator it can be  espace or , or - ......
  fisrt =result[0] // aaa
  second =result[1] //bbb
  thrid = result[2] // ccc

}
```